# What does "Ergodic Convergence Rate" mean?

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, ergodic-theory, numerical-optimization

While reading some Optimization papers (such as  [this one](http://www.optimization-online.org/DB_FILE/2020/08/7990.pdf)) I came across the term "ergodic convergence rate", but I have been unable to find its definition.

As an example, the linked paper talks about an algorithm being

> "...convergent with an $\mathcal{O}(1/k)$ ergodic convergence rate, where $k$ denotes the iteration number."

Does this mean that if $x^*$ is the solution and $(x_k)$ is the main sequence produced by the algorithm, then $||x_k - x^*|| = \mathcal{O}(1/k)$?

Thank you very much.

Comment: This refers to the gap $f(x^{(k)})-f(x^{*})$ rather than $\|  x^{(k)}-x^{*} \|$.  Since the algorithm is stochastic there is no actual guarantee of convergence, but there will be convergence in some averaged sense.

Comment: @BrianBorchers Thank you very much! So it's not even $\mathbb{E}[f(x^{(k)})-f(x^{*})]$, it's just $f(x^{(k)})-f(x^{*})$. If you'd like to post your comment as an answer I would be very happy to accept it!

Comment: No, it is some kind of averaged (or expected value) of $f(x^{(k)})-f(x^{*})$.  The worst case is that the algorithm fails to improve the objective value after (for example) repeatedly using the same gradient over and over again.

Comment: @BrianBorchers I understand, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ergodic convergence rate specifies convergence rate of $\bar{x}_n = 1/n \sum_{k=1}^n x^{(k)}$ to optimal solution $x^{*}$. Non-ergodic convergence rate specifies convergence rate of $x^{(k)}$ to $x^{*}$.

Comment: "ergodic convergence" can apply to both iterates (as above) and function values too, e.g., the rate at which $1/n\sum_{k=1}^n f(x_k) - f(x^*)$ converges towards zero